# No resources.txt file created after using shrinkResources with proguard in android?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, shrinkresources

actually I am trying to use **shrinkResources** in my android project, now I have added below lines in my gradle file:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
zipAlignEnabled true
```

Now when I try to run my app, it does not creates any **resources.txt** file which according to docs below should have been created. [resource-shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking)

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong because of which no **resources.txt** file is creating.

Please help me guys, it would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your gradle config. [detail](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=132465)
you can see resources.txt under mapping dir.
or
`./gradlew --debug clean assembleRelease`
and what you want will show in console. [detail](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80872)